# "No such file or directory" but it's there.

Tags: directory

I'm a total newbie to Ubuntu and Linux and I'm struggling to even navigate to folders. The below often happens -

```
brian2@ubuntu:~$ cd /home/
brian2@ubuntu:/home$ cd /brian2
bash: cd: /brian2: No such file or directory
brian2@ubuntu:/home$ l
brian/  brian2/  fslyne/  testuser/
```

As you can see from the above I'm trying to go to the folder `brian2` but Ubuntu tells me `No such file or directory` but the directory list command tells me it is there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to Ubuntu.

From home to enter `brian2` from `/home/`, type in terminal

```
cd ./brian2
```

or simply,

```
cd brian2
```

When to say `cd /brian2`, it tries to navigate the folder at `/` but there is no folder `brian2`

---

#### Further Clarification as you asked in your comment

Christian Mann aptly said it, tilde `~` refers the same thing as /home/brian2 in your case.

`~` refers to home for any user. For example,

For brian `~` refers to `/home/brian`

For brian1 `~` refers to `/home/brian1` so on.

If brian1 enters to brian's home (have to have permission) he will see at prompt

```
brian1@ubuntu:/home/brian$
```

In Linux always you can modify things. There is a special shell variable `PS1` which can modify the shell prompt in different ways as you wish.

Comment: Just to clarify, the point is that `/` refers to the very top of the hierarchy of your system. `home` is a top-level directory under `/` so `/home` refers to the `home` directory at the top of the hierarchy and `/home/brian2` refers to the `brian2` directory inside the `home` directory, whereas `/brian2` refers to the non-existent `brian2` directory at the top of the hierarchy. `cd` can also check the current directory, so if you are in `/home` already, it will go to `/home/brian2` if you type `cd brian2`. `cd /home/brian2` does the same thing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, Souravc. I entered the following:

Comment: brian2@ubuntu:~$ cd /home   .......       
brian2@ubuntu:/home$ cd brian2     ........     
brian2@ubuntu:~$

Comment: I would have thought it would have brought me to ...... brian2@ubuntu:/home/brian2$ 
?? Thanks for your patience! Brian

Comment: I see. I didn't know it I was actually pointing to the root folder by using a '/' . Makes more sense now. Thanks again !

Comment: @brian If this answer has answered your question please [accept it](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/44179) to help keep our site clean and orderly. Thanks!

Comment: Will do Seth. Sorry I never saw the accept link.

Answer (score 5):

`/brian2` doesn't exist. `/home/brian2` does exist. If you are already inside `/home` then you simply need to run `cd brian2` to get into that directory. If you are already that user, then `cd` will switch to your home directory, when you run it without arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dobey. I tried that (as per my message to Souravc below) but got back brian2@ubuntu:-$
Any idea why it wouldn't say brian2@ubuntu:/home/brian2 ?
Maybe Souravc will answer so I don't want to bother both of you. Thanks again, Brian

Comment: See that tilde? `~` means the same thing as `/home/brian2`. It's a convenient shortcut when you want to go to your home directory quickly, i.e. `cd ~`.